# Number of entries between dates

Tags: postgresql, amazon-redshift

I have a table with the following structure: -

```
day,        id
2016-03-13, 123
2016-03-13, 123
2016-03-13, 231
2016-03-14, 231
2016-03-14, 231
2016-03-15, 129
```

And I'd like to build a table that looks like: -

```
id,   d1, d7, d14
123,  1,  1,  1
231,  1,  2,  2
129,  1,  1,  1
```

Essentially for a given id, list the number of days which have an entry within a time window. So if id 123 has 10 entries within the last 14 days - d14 would be 10.

So far I have: -

```
    SELECT
        day,
        id
    FROM
        events
    WHERE
        datediff (DAY, day, getdate()) <= 7
    GROUP BY
        day,
        id
```

Comment: What are those "last 14 days"? From today?

Comment: @LukasEder Yup, updated the question to reflect that with `getdate()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query will do:

```
SELECT
    id,
    COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN current_date - day <=  1 THEN 1 END) d1,
    COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN current_date - day <=  7 THEN 1 END) d7,
    COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN current_date - day <= 14 THEN 1 END) d14
FROM
    events
GROUP BY
    id
ORDER BY
    id
```

Or, since PostgreSQL 9.4, slightly more concise:

```
SELECT
    id,
    COUNT(DISTINCT day) FILTER (WHERE current_date - day <=  1) d1,
    COUNT(DISTINCT day) FILTER (WHERE current_date - day <=  7) d7,
    COUNT(DISTINCT day) FILTER (WHERE current_date - day <= 14) d14
FROM
    events
GROUP BY
    id
ORDER BY
    id
```

Comment: Thank you, I think thats close, I'm getting counts above the dN values, is there a way to make it work on distinct dates?

Comment: This looks like the ticket, added a subquery  (SELECT DISTINCT events.day, id FROM events) r

Comment: @martinblank You can use distinct inside aggregate functions as well, like `COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN current_date - day <=  1 THEN day END)` or `COUNT(DISTINCT day) FILTER (...)`

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
SELECT id
, count(case when DAY = getdate() then 1 else null end) as d1
, count(case when DAY + 7 >= getdate() then 1 else null end) as d7
, count(case when DAY + 14 >= getdate() then 1 else null end) as d14
FROM events
WHERE DAY between DAY >= getdate() - 14 
--or if you can have day > today ...  and DAY between getdate() - 14 and getdate()
GROUP By id
```